# Namespaced controller testing error on resource_url (inherited_resources)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, namespaces

I am using inherited_resources and I have a controller like:

```
class Admin::PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
end
```

And in my controller test:

```
it "redirects to the post" do
  post = Post.create! valid_attributes
  put :update, {:id => post.to_param, :post => valid_attributes}, valid_session
  response.should redirect_to([:admin, post])
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `posts_url' for #<Admin::PostsController:0xec6fb20>
```

The weird part is that it is only happening in the tests! The application runs ok.

What am I missing?

[EDIT] I found this issue reported, but was closed without an answer https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/issues/193

[EDIT] I just found why it is happening and responded on the above issue page

Comment: can you post the answer here or close the question so it doesn't show up as "unanswered"?

Answer (score 1):

have u tried this:

```
response.should redirect_to '/your_url'
```

it may be solved your problem.